# Transfer photos from iPhone to PC

Tags: iphone, windows, photos

I'm trying to upload all my pictures (around 4,000) to my Windows computer from my iPhone.  I have tried using the Explorer method, but it only copies around 10 items.  I also tried importing using the Photos app, but that gives me an error around 10 pictures in.  Is there an app I could use to transfer them to my computer?  I've had good luck with iMazing, but it costs quite a bit.  I would prefer to do this for free if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: This is the error from Photos: https://ibb.co/MndpzPM
Explorer doesn't give an error.  It just acts like its finished copying after 10 items.

Comment: Can you try after rebooting both devices? And with a different cable?

Comment: I will try that when I get a chance, but this has been happening for years. I’ve tried different computers, different cables, and even reset my phone.

Comment: That‘s strange...

Comment: Oh wait.  I'll try doing it on my Mac and moving it over to my Windows computer.  Don't know why I didn't think of that before :).

Comment: I got the pictures that way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it over USB is incredibly difficult, I've had those same issues where it won't transfer more than a few at a time.  In fact, I've been having that issue since way back when I owned an iPhone 4S ten years ago.

Using something like Readdle's [Documents](https://readdle.com/documents) app or something like [LanDrop](https://landrop.app/) works well for transferring media over the web.  There are lots of options for doing it that way.

But, if you're transferring a lot of files at once and prefer to do it via lightning cable connection, SanDisk's [iXpand Drive](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-ixpand-usb-3-0#SDIX30C-032G-AN6NN) is really great.  It's basically a flash drive you plug into your phone via lightning, and it can quickly copy lots of media at once.  Then you plug the other end into your PC when you're finished, and you're all set.

It would be wonderful if there were a a way to do it with a direct lightning connection to either a PC or Mac, but that's unfortunately just not something easily done with the way iOS handles things.